# Save File to a given location without Open/Save Dialogue Box ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, ms-word, render

```
public static void ServeAsPDF(System.Web.UI.Page webPage, Boolean download, String FileName)
{
    try
    {
        string htmlString = GetHtmlForPage(webPage);

        webPage.Response.Buffer = true;
        webPage.Response.Clear();
        webPage.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-word"; //application/octet-stream
        webPage.Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.UnicodeEncoding.UTF8;
        webPage.Response.Charset = "UTF-8";
        webPage.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition:", "attachment; filename="+ FileName +"");
        webPage.Response.AddHeader("cache-control", "must-revalidate");


        webPage.Response.Write("<html xmlns:v='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml' xmlns:o='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office' xmlns:w='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word'  xmlns:m='http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2004/12/omml' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40'>");
        webPage.Response.Write("<head>");
        webPage.Response.Write("<title>PF FUND</title>");
        webPage.Response.Write("<META HTTP-EQUIV='Content-Type' CONTENT='text/html; charset=UTF-8'>");
        webPage.Response.Write("<meta name=ProgId content=Word.Document>");
        webPage.Response.Write("<meta name=Generator content='Microsoft Word 9'>");
        webPage.Response.Write("<meta name=Originator content='Microsoft Word 9'>");
        webPage.Response.Write("<!--[if gte mso 9]> <xml> <w:WordDocument> <w:View>Print</w:View> <w:Zoom>100</w:Zoom> <w:DoNotOptimizeForBrowser/> </w:WordDocument> </xml> <![endif]-->");
        webPage.Response.Write("<style>");
        webPage.Response.Write("@page { size: 8.27in 11.69in; mso-page-orientation: Portrait Orientation; }");
        webPage.Response.Write("@page Section1 {margin:0.5in 0.5in 0.5in 0.5in;mso-paper-source:0;}");
        webPage.Response.Write("div.Section1 {page:Section1;}");
        webPage.Response.Write("@page Section2 {size:841.7pt 595.45pt;mso-page-orientation:landscape;margin:1.0in 1.0in 1.0in 1.0in;mso-header-margin:.5in;mso-footer-margin:.5in;mso-paper-source:0;}");
        webPage.Response.Write("div.Section2 {page:Section2;}");
        webPage.Response.Write("</style>");
        webPage.Response.Write("</head>");
        webPage.Response.Write("<body>");
        webPage.Response.Write("<div class=Section1>");
        webPage.Response.Write(htmlString);
        webPage.Response.Write("</div>");
        webPage.Response.Write("</body>");
        webPage.Response.Write("</html>");
        webPage.Response.Flush();
        webPage.Response.End();
    }
    catch
    {
        //Handle Exception
    }
}
public static string GetHtmlForPage(System.Web.UI.Page PgIn)
{
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    Panel Panel1 = (Panel)PgIn.FindControl("Panel1");
    Panel1.RenderControl(htw);
    return sw.ToString();
}
```

I used this code to generate word file from an aspx page. But my problem is, i need to generate pdf from this word file. So i want to read the word file, save it in byte array and render the bye array as PDF.

But this word file is generated on client side. I need to save this file on server, then read this word file and generate pdf so that user can view only PDF, not the word File..

Previously i tried to convert webpage to PDF but failed to do so..so i found it easy to generate a word file and then convert it into PDF ..

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use Office [InterOp](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316384) to create word document and if you want create pdf then use [iText](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) api.

Comment: @ adatapost

Hi, Thanks for ur response.

I tried iTextSharp Free Library to convert aspx page to PDF. But after reading its documentation, i came to know that iTextSharp can not apply HTML Table css styles. We need to create pdfTables, apply styles to them and fill the cells dynamically. I i do this way, i will loose my table formatting.

So is there any way to convery HTMl table (with css) in aspx page to pdf using iTextSharp widout creating pdfTables ?